# How to past in text box only 7 digits

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form in a web app for  android.
one of the fields is a text box that getting auto numbers from the location of the device.
but the problem is that I need only 7 numbers and it's pasting much more, how can I restrict this field with js and it's will paste only the first 7 numbers? I tried to do max length and js valid code, but nothing worked, it's still pasting a lot of numbers.
Thanks,
Jordan

Comment: What browser and code you are using? Also provide the HTML

Answer (score 3):

Could you paste the HTML code for you input? The maxlength attribute should definitely work.

it should look like:

```
<input type="number" maxlength="7" size="7">
```

*note - the size attribute alone won't actually limit the amount of characters your input can accept.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't have the option to comment. Do I need a certain amount of reputation to comment on the OP's question?

Comment: Looks like you need 50 rep minimum to comment on a post http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the size attribute to be 7. The below example works even if the type is different from "text".

```
<input type="text" size="7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the attribute you are looking for is [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input).

```
<input type="text" maxlength="7" />
```

> **`maxlength`** [HTML5]
>
> **If the value of the type attribute is text, email,search, password, tel, or url, this attribute specifies the maximum number of characters (in Unicode code points) that the user can enter**; for other control types, it is ignored. It can exceed the value of the size attribute. If it is not specified, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. Specifying a negative number results in the default behavior; that is, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. The constraint is evaluated only when the value of the attribute has been changed.

Comment: But the max length working only when I am typing a value, but when I'm pasting some value it's not working, or in my case when I'm getting it from js script.